# php -$result->fetch_array does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a table within my database with a GET Method.
Now when I hardcode the value of the variable in there (the table name) it works as expected and it returns the values in an array.

But when I try to determine the table name through a variable, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Now I have tried the `var_dump($result);` but that returns `bool(false)`.

Now the variable does carry a value, because when I echo it back to the screen it gives the value I would expect.

So why does not return the value when making the query for my table search???

```
     $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons  WHERE sermonSeries = ". $series); //This where a change needs to happen

    var_dump($result);

        $posts = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {    
            $ID=$row['ID'];
            $sermonTitle=$row['sermonTitle'];
            $sermonSpeaker=$row['sermonSpeaker'];
            $sermonSeries=$row['sermonSeries'];
            $sermonDate=$row['sermonDate'];
            $linkToImage=$row['linkToImage'];
            $linkToAudioFile=$row['linkToAudioFile'];

            $posts []= array (
                'ID'=> $ID,
                'sermonTitle'=> $sermonTitle,
                'sermonSpeaker'=> $sermonSpeaker,
                'sermonSeries'=> $sermonSeries,
                'sermonDate'=> $sermonDate,
                'linkToImage'=> $linkToImage,
                'linkToAudioFile'=> $linkToAudioFile
            );
    }

    $response['posts'] = $posts;

    var_dump($posts);
```

PS I have read about the depreciation in mysql style and that I know have to use mysqli writing. I am running PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny16

Comment: Your query is failing, which is why `$result` is false. The error will be available in `$mysqli->error` after the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `$series` is a string you need to put quotes around the variable..

Try...

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons  WHERE sermonSeries = '". $series ."'");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I have tried the `var_dump($result);` but that returns `bool(false)`.

Because your query failed.

Try:

```
if( ! $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons  WHERE sermonSeries = ". $series); ) {
  echo "An error has occurred: \n" . var_export($mysqli->error_list, TRUE);
} else {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This now gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::var_export()

Comment: @JeffKranenburg yeah, I just noticed the broken `$mysqli->var_export()` bit and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons  WHERE sermonSeries = ". $series); //This where a change needs to happen`

You should be using Prepared Statements if the variable: `$series` is user defined.

```
$result->prepare("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons WHERE `sermonSeries`=?");
$result->bind_param('s', $series);
$result->execute();
```

Also, Print_r($result); to check if your initial `$result` to see if it has been populated; Furthermore, in your SQL Query is `sermonSeries` properly matched to your SQL Table?

**Update:**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
        {
```

Try Modifying this to:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Your code does not help me, after trying it sorry - yes the variable is exactly the same - I copied and pasted it to be sure:-)

Answer (score 1):

The central question seems to me: Where does `$series` come from? Where does that variable ever get initialized?

If you're passing this in from the web form, two things: either use `$_GET` or `$_POST` (whatever action you use in your form). And then you have to sanitize what comes from there, in order to not be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Prepared statements are your friend in this case; they help harden your script against this kind of attacks.

Comment: It gets initialized at the top after <?php - $series = $_GET['series']; and at the moment it is just coming from a url, which will get changed later - http://url.com/test.php?series=nameOfTable

Comment: Then I think I know what is happening: You need to have quotes around the string for the query to work: ... `where series = '".$series."'"`

Comment: Also, do yourself the favor and invest the time to make this into a prepared statement. It's worth the time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSermons  WHERE sermonSeries = '$series' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

your query simply fails. check var_dump($series); before executing.

i assume it might be a string and you just don't quote it?

just a tip: first build a string with your commandtext before 
calling $mysqli->query. and use that string (like $mysqli->query($cmd);

dump that string :) might open your eyes ;)

that way you can extract it and execute it directly against the database (f.e. phpmyadmin).

Comment: When I pass it to another variable and echo, print and whatever I can think of, there seems to be no issue.